# Javascript type coercion using parseFloat().toFixed()?

Tags: javascript

Can Someone explain this thoroughly,why the third expression returns NaN?

```
NaN || 0 // 0 
parseFloat("s").toFixed() // NaN 
parseFloat("s").toFixed() || 0 // NaN
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Line 1: NaN is falsey, therefore `NaN || 0` becomes 0

the method `.toFixed` results in a string, so

Line 2: `parseFloat("s")` -> `NaN` (this is the **value** `NaN`), then `NaN.toFixed()` -> `"NaN"` ... hence the result is the STRING "NaN" (not the value NaN)

Line 3: same as Line2, then, as a non-empty string is "truthy", `"NaN" || 0` -> `"NaN"` (note, still a string)

P.S. I don't think there's any type coercion going on here (I may be wrong though)

Comment: You made it very clear , the key point here is that .toFixed returns a string instead of number even if it's dealing with a valid float number , am I right ?

Comment: sort of ... `.toFixed` is a method of a javascript `Number` object that returns a `String`, `NaN` (despite meaning not a number) is a javascript `Number`, so, toFixed returns a `String` ... oh, and yes, toFixed **always** returns a `String`

Answer (score 1):

This is because you get `"NAN" || 0` not `NAN || 0` as `parseFloat("s").toFixed` will return `"NAN"` not `NAN`

Comment: no ... `parseFloat('s')` actually returns `NaN` not `"NaN"`